# Logging Android navigation

Tags: android, android-activity, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I have an android app that uses activities for navigation.

I want to log events to my error handler when a user navigates to a new activity.

There must be a way of doing this without adding some call to a logging function on every `startActivity` as the Firebase Analytics we are currently using [does this just by including the library](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/screenviews#kotlin+ktx).

The source code for Analytics is not public but does anyone have any idea how they might be doing this?

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems to be registering [Lifecycle Observers](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle) and [Activity Lifecycle Callbacks](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks)

I found an open-source library that does the same thing [here](https://github.com/segmentio/analytics-android/blob/master/analytics/src/main/java/com/segment/analytics/AnalyticsActivityLifecycleCallbacks.java)